# BMP280 Reports Odd Output RPi

Tags: raspberry-pi, i2c

My BMP280 attached to my RPi0W is reporting a consistent 133.90 degrees Celcius (should be around 25 degrees....) Similarly is reporting over 5 million Pascals pressure (should be around 100,000.)

> Temp = 133.90 *C Pressure = 5611578.00 Pa Altitude = -50829.45 m
>   Sealevel Pressure = 5611578.00 Pa

I'm using the Adafruit Python test program (only 6 lines of code....no error indication) Only change I made was to reference I2C address of 0x76 instead of the default 0x77, since I'm not using the Adafruit brand BMP280.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# Copyright (c) 2014 Adafruit Industries
# Author: Tony DiCola
#
# Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
# of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
# in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
# to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
# copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
# furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
#
# The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
# all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
#
# THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
# IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
# FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
# AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
# LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
# OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN
# THE SOFTWARE.

# Can enable debug output by uncommenting:
#import logging
#logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

import Adafruit_BMP.BMP085 as BMP085

# Default constructor will pick a default I2C bus.
#
# For the Raspberry Pi this means you should hook up to the only exposed I2C bus
# from the main GPIO header and the library will figure out the bus number based
# on the Pi's revision.
#
# For the Beaglebone Black the library will assume bus 1 by default, which is
# exposed with SCL = P9_19 and SDA = P9_20.
sensor = BMP085.BMP085(address=0x76)

# Optionally you can override the bus number:
#sensor = BMP085.BMP085(busnum=2)

# You can also optionally change the BMP085 mode to one of BMP085_ULTRALOWPOWER,
# BMP085_STANDARD, BMP085_HIGHRES, or BMP085_ULTRAHIGHRES.  See the BMP085
# datasheet for more details on the meanings of each mode (accuracy and power
# consumption are primarily the differences).  The default mode is STANDARD.
#sensor = BMP085.BMP085(mode=BMP085.BMP085_ULTRAHIGHRES)
print(sensor.read_temperature())
print('Temp = {0:0.2f} *C'.format(sensor.read_temperature()))
print('Pressure = {0:0.2f} Pa'.format(sensor.read_pressure()))
print('Altitude = {0:0.2f} m'.format(sensor.read_altitude()))
print('Sealevel Pressure = {0:0.2f} Pa'.format(sensor.read_sealevel_pressure()))
```

The Adafruit detector does detect I2C address 0x76 properly.

DHT11 attached to same board is reporting roughly accurate temp of 84 degrees F (it was sitting in the exhaust stream from my laptop...lol)

What should I check for?

Comment: You should show your code, and identify the actual brand of device you are using. The output of `i2cdetect` might be useful. Also versions of relevant software.

Comment: I2Detect had all zeros except second last cell had "76".

Comment: Added code to OP

Answer (score 0):

Brand of device is "gybmep". After some additional searching, I find I may have been using the wrong Adafruit library. I found another approach at

["USING THE BMP280 TEMP/PRESS SENSOR ON THE RASPBERRY PI
"](http://faradaysclub.com/?p=1325)

Seems I should have been using the Adafruit BME280 libraries. From that library example code, I got reasonable results.